# How to get screen dimensions in c# (xamarin cross platform app)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

For my app I need to get the screens dimensions, I have seen people use the System.Windows.Forms namespace but I'm not able to find this package. when I search for this NuGet package it doesn't want to show up.

Does any know why this is happening? If you know another solution to get the screens dimensions please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Xamarin.Essential NuGet package to get the height and width and other display information.

Nuget Docs:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/?context=xamarin/android

And within that you can use Device Display Information:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/device-display?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=ios

Thanks!